# Convert ID number into date format in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, numeric

I have ID's stored into the ID column in table `TEMP_SDR_RECEIVED` which has value for example:
`201505264865645884`. The year,month and date is stored in this ID format in the first 8 numbers. I want to extract the year,month,date from this ID and want to set the minute,hour,seconds to `00:00:00` and others values to null in the column `ID_DATE` which is date data type. So the conversion of ID into date format should look like this : `26.05.15 00:00:00` 
I am trying following query but getting an error as the hour must be between 1 to 23. 
Here is my query:

```
Insert into TEMP_SDR_RECEIVED(ID_DATE)
    Select to_date(substr(ID, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM TEMP_SDR_RECEIVED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the 8 first characters then :

```
Insert into TEMP_SDR_RECEIVED(ID_DATE)
Select to_date(substr(ID, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD') FROM TEMP_SDR_RECEIVED
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1854).

By default, the hours / min / seconds will be set to 0

Comment: ohh ok its working i thought it might give an error :) thank you :)